# Install a package into multiple/all conda environments?

Tags: python, conda

I'm using conda to run tests against different versions of python, numpy, etc., but there are some common dependencies for all combinations of python/numpy.  Is there a way to install such packages into *all* conda environments, or do I have to specify each by hand?

Comment: Hey, if my answer worked for you, can you please accept it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can run a shell loop over the output of `conda env list`.  For example:

```
for env in $(conda env list | cut -d" " -f1 | tail -n+4); do conda install -n $env XXXXXX; done
```

Answer (score 8):

There's no simple command to do this, but one thing that may help is to make a metapackage using the `conda metapackage` command that depends on the packages you want, so that you can install just it. Something like `conda metapackage mypackage 1.0 --dependencies package1 package2 package3 ...`.

Otherwise, you probably just need to make clever use of `xargs`.

Comment: Technically, that's not part of `conda`, but rather [`conda-build`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/commands/conda-metapackage.html). Still useful.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using a `for` loop in @abalter's answer, you can do it with xargs too.
Note, this will only work for environment names without spaces:

```
conda env list | cut -d" " -f1 | tail -n+4 | xargs -L 1 conda install YOUR_PACKAGE -n
```