# Install Packages Onto All Anaconda Environments

Tags: python, shell, anaconda

I have a large number (~20) of different Anaconda environments and a list of Python packages like dill, csvkit, and so forth that I need to make available on all of those environments.

What's a concise, non-manual way of getting the packages I want onto all of the Anaconda environments?

[On this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117449/install-a-package-into-multiple-all-conda-environments) I've seen that making a metapackage out of it and then using a shell script to install that metapackage on each environment iteratively might be an avenue, but I don't see much info online about how to use metapackages for installation purposes.

Comment: I would just use the Command line loop given by the highest ranked answer from the question you posted

Answer (score 0):

Put the list of packages you require in a text file, e.g.,

**packages.txt**

```
dill
csvkit
...
```

<sup>**Note**: This file can also include versions, channels, and builds. Basically, anything that you can output with `conda list --export`.</sup>

Then run a loop similar to that found in the other answer,

```
for env in $(conda env list | awk '/^[a-zA-Z]/' | cut -d' ' -f1); do
    conda install -n "$env" --file packages.txt;
done
```

Perhaps the `-y|--yes` and `-q|--quiet` might also be useful in this context.