# "~/miniconda3/bin" does not prepended to PATH for custom environments

Tags: terminal, conda

I use conda 4.7.11 with `auto_activate_base: false` in `~/.condarc`. I installed `htop` using `conda install -c conda-forge htop`. It was installed at `~/miniconda3/bin/htop`. When I am in `base` environment I am able to use `htop` because `~/miniconda3/bin` is prepended to `PATH` variable. But when I am outside all environments then only `~/miniconda3/condabin` is prepended to `PATH`. When I am in all other environments except `base` then `~/miniconda3/envs/CUSTOM_ENV/bin` and `~/miniconda3/condabin` are prepended to `PATH` but not `~/miniconda3/bin`, that's why I can use `htop` only from `base` environment. So my question is about how to be able to use `htop` installed using `conda` from all environments, including case when all environments are deactivated.

Please, don't suggest using package managers like `apt` or `yum` in my case (CentOS), because I have no root access to use this package manager. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conda environments aren't nested, so what is in **base** is not inherited by the others. Isolation of environments is the imperative requirement, so it should make sense that the content in **base** env is not accessible when it isn't activated.

## Option 1: Environment Stacking

However, there is an option to explicitly stack environments, which at this point literally means what you're asking for, namely, keeping the previous enviroment's `bin/` in the `PATH` variable.  So, if you `htop` installed only in **base**, then you can retain access to it in other envs like so

```
conda activate base
conda activate --stack my_env
```

If you decide to go this route, I think it would be prudent to be very minimal about what you install in **base**.  Of course, you could also create a non-**base** env to stack on, but then it might be a bother to have to always activate this env, whereas in default installs, **base** auto-activates.

Starting with Conda v4.8 there will be an `auto_stack` configuration option:

```
conda config --set auto_stack true
```

See [the documentation on environment stacking](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/master/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#nested-activation) for details.

## Option 2: Install by Default

If you want to have `htop` in every env but not outside of Conda envs, then the naive solution is to install it in every env. [Conda offers a simple solution to this called **Default Packages**](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#config-add-default-pkgs), and is in the Conda config under the key `create_default_packages`.  Running the following will tell Conda to always install `htop` when creating a new env:

```
conda config --add create_default_packages htop
```

Unfortunately that won't update any existing envs, so you'd still have to go back and do that (e.g., [Install a package into all envs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117449/install-a-package-into-multiple-all-conda-environments)). There's also a `--no-default-packages` flag for ignoring default packages when creating new envs.

## Option 3: Global Installs

#### A Word of Caution

The following two options are not official recommendations, so *caveat emptor* and, if you do ever use them, be sure to report such a non-standard manipulation of `$PATH` when reporting problems/troubleshooting in the future.

#### Linking

Another option (although more manual) is to create a folder in your user directory (e.g., `~/.local/bin`) that you add to `$PATH` in your `.bashrc` and create links in there to the binaries that you wish to "export" globally. I do this with a handful of programs that I wanted to use independently of Conda (e.g., `emacs`) even though they are installed and managed by Conda.

#### Dedicated Env

If you plan to do this with a bunch of software, then it might work to dedicate an env to such global software and just add its whole `./bin` dir to `$PATH`. Do not do this with **base** - Conda wants to strictly manage that itself since Conda v4.4. Furthermore, do not do this with anything Python-related: **stick strictly to native (compiled) software** (e.g., `htop` is a good example).  If an additional Python of the same version ends up on your `$PATH` this can create a mess in library loading. I've never attempted this and prefer the manual linking because I know exactly what I'm exporting.

Comment: I think default installation is ok for me, thank you!

Comment: @thmw FYI, I've updated the answer to cover the option of stacking envs, which might be an even better solution for your case, since it would avoid having to reinstall in every env.